# Front and rear card animation only with css and html

Tags: html, css, animation

I like to add some animation effect to my webpage, have to add cards in below specified format with front and behind effects. when i click any card it must come front and all other cards are go behind to front card.

Initially my cards be like this.,[image: Initial card]
After click action my cards be like this.,[image: After click action]

Here my Html Code

```
<div class="cardlist" align="center">
<div class="card" style="float:left;">
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon-2.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Notification" value="Email">Email
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="float:left;">
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon-2.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="float:left;">
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
                <img src="Assert/Settings-icon-2.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                    <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

and my CSS code

```
 .card {
padding: 30px;
background: #fff;
/*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
transition: 0.3s;
width: 10%;
}

.card:hover .cardlarge , .card.hover .cardlarge {
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width: 20%;
}

.container {
padding: 2px 16px;
}

.cardlarge {
padding: 30px;
background: #fff;
transition: 0.3s;
width: 20%;
}
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.front {
z-index: 2;
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


.back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: “Talk is cheap. Show me the code.”

Comment: So how much money are you offering for us to code this for you?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I still didn't try anything because I don't know how to do this.. please guide me to do this

Comment: On click it's impossible only with CSS, you have to use javascript. Try something.

Comment: I tried some thing, but still i cant achieve my goal, please guide me! and i post my code whatever i tred